# What are the correct typescript compiler (tsc) options to set in order to separate main from test compilation?

Tags: typescript, tsc

*NB: A public git repo for this question is at https://github.com/matthewadams/ts-test if you want to have a look at the full project.*

I'm trying to separate main source compilation from test source compilation in my project.  Here's the source directory structure:

```
src
  main
    ...typescript source files and possibly child directories with sources
  test
    unit
      ...unit test sources
    integration
      ...integration test sources
```

My goal is to compile *only* main sources into `lib/main`, and *only* test sources into `lib/test`.

I'm trying to put all compiler options that should be common to both main & test compilations in `tsconfig.json`, then use command-line args to `tsc` to provide the options that are specific to each compilation.  Here's my current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "diagnostics": true,
    "disableSizeLimit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "extendedDiagnostics": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "listEmittedFiles": true,
    "listFiles": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

A snippet from `package.json` `scripts` section is the following (I reject Gulp, Grunt & the like on the grounds of complexity, knowingly sacrificing portability):

```
  "scripts": {
    "transpile-main": "rm -rf lib/main && tsc --outDir lib/main --rootDir src/main -d --declarationDir lib/main",
    "transpile-test": "rm -rf lib/test && tsc --outDir lib/test --rootDir src/test --typeRoots lib/main",
    ...other scripts here...
  }
```

I can compile main sources without an issue, and they appear in `lib/main` correctly.  However, when I compile test sources, I get the following error:

```
$ npm run transpile-test

> @matthewadams/ts-test@0.1.0-pre.0 transpile-test /Users/matthewadams/dev/me/ts-test
> rm -rf lib/test && tsc --outDir lib/test --rootDir src/test --typeRoots src/main

error TS6059: File '/Users/matthewadams/dev/me/ts-test/src/main/Nameable.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'src/test'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File '/Users/matthewadams/dev/me/ts-test/src/main/Person.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'src/test'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File '/Users/matthewadams/dev/me/ts-test/src/main/PersonImpl.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'src/test'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

The thing that's confusing me is the message `'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`  I'm trying to compile test sources against what's in *`lib/main`*.  I don't want all sources under one directory.

What is the correct combination of `tsconfig.json` options & `tsc` cli options to achieve my goal of separate main & test compilations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Error: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

`rootDir` is expected to be the root of all source/input files. TS compiler proceeds like this:

```
collect all input files ("files" / "include" / "exclude" / imports) 
  --> for each included input file
    --> chop off the "rootDir" from the input 
    --> prepend the "outDir"
```

The `src/test` files import from `src/main`, so currently `rootDir` can only be set to `src` or above.

### Solution: Project References (TS 3.0+)

[Project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) can solve all of the issues you described:

- `rootDir` will be set to `src/main` or `src/test` respectively
- `src` folder does not appear as part of  the `lib` output
- `src/main` cannot import `src/test` (only vice versa should be possible)

Resulting project structure:

```
|   tsconfig-base.json            // other config options go here
|   tsconfig.json                 // solution config containing references
|   
+---lib                           // output folder
|   +---main
|   |       mod.d.ts
|   |       mod.js
|   |       tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
|   |       
|   \---test
|           mod-test.js     
\---src
    +---main                      // referenced sub-project main 
    |       mod.ts
    |       tsconfig.json
    |       
    \---test                      // referenced sub-project test 
            mod-test.ts
            tsconfig.json
```

./tsconfig-base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // just some sample values, set your own as needed
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // other compiler options
  }
}
```

./tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./src/main"
    },
    {
      "path": "./src/test"
    }
  ]
}
```

./src/main/mod.ts:

```
export const foo = "foo";
```

./src/main/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../lib/main",
    "composite": true // flag to signal referenced project      
  }
}
```

./src/test/mod-test.ts:

```
import { foo } from "../main/mod";

// use your test framework here
export function testMod() {
  if (foo !== "foo") throw new Error("foo expected.");
}

testMod()
```

./src/test/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../lib/test"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../main" // test project depends on main
    }
  ]
}
```

You can build and clean the project with following [scripts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -b -v",
    "clean": "tsc -b --clean"
},
```

#### Further links

- [TypeScript Project References Demo](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/project-references-demo)

Comment: Ok, that inspired me enough to go with the `tsconfig` inheritance route.  I have a `tsconfig.common.json` that's extended by `tsconfig.main.json` for the `src/main` compilation to directory `dist`, and by `tsconfig.test.json`, which compiles _both_ `src/main` & `src/test` to `lib`, then I run the tests from `lib/test` (to ensure that the transpiled code has no failing tests).  While not an answer per se, I'll go ahead & mark your response as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I've also pushed the commits to https://github.com/matthewadams/ts-test as well, if any followers want to have a looky-poo.